# Relocate rows with tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, relocate

Is it possible to `relocate` **rows** in `tidyverse` framework like it is possible for columns with `dplyr` `relocate`?

In this example I would like to relocate row 1 to position 5 (end of dataframe)

My dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), var1 = c("a", "b", "c", 
"d", "e"), var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

df
  ID var1 var2
1  1    a    1
2  2    b    1
3  3    c    0
4  4    d    0
5  5    e    1
```

Desired output:

```
  ID var1 var2
1  2    b    1
2  3    c    0
3  4    d    0
4  5    e    1
5  1    a    1
```

Note: In the it should be 'pipe friendly' solution. I tried a lot but found nothing. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`arrange()` is the tidyverse verb for reordering rows. It can be (ab)used as follows:

```r
dplyr::arrange(df, ID==1)
```

(`ID==1` is logical; when it is ordered `FALSE` values come before `TRUE` values ...)

This isn't as flexible as `relocate()` (e.g. it's not immediately obvious how to say "move rows 100-200 so they are immediately after row 1000"), but you can probably find a way to do most tasks.

Another option (less idiomatic in my opinion) is `slice()`:

```r
dplyr::slice(df, order(ID==1))
```

(this is a tidyverse translation of @akrun's base-R answer). Either of these solutions can also be written with pipes (e.g. `df %>% arrange(ID==1)`).

Just to be silly:

```r
df %>% `[`(order(.$ID==1),)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `base R`

```
df[order(df$ID == 1), ]
```

---

Or with `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    slice(2:n(), 1)
```

Or specify with `row_number()`

```
df %>% 
   slice(lead(row_number(), default = 1))
```

Comment: These are nice. I still think `arrange()` is most idiomatic ...

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is not so elegant but here is a way:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(between(row_number(), 2, nrow(df))) %>%
  bind_rows(df[1, ])

  ID var1 var2
1  2    b    1
2  3    c    0
3  4    d    0
4  5    e    1
5  1    a    1
```

Comment: This is good, but there must be a better solution! Thank you dear my friend!

Comment: `bind_rows` was a good direction together with the other answers to get to my answer!

Comment: You're welcome dear friend, glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's play a math trick

```
> df[order((seq(nrow(df)) -2) %% nrow(df)), ]
  ID var1 var2
2  2    b    1
3  3    c    0
4  4    d    0
5  5    e    1
1  1    a    1
```

or

```
> df %>%
+   arrange(replace(row_number(), 1, n() + 1))
  ID var1 var2
1  2    b    1
2  3    c    0
3  4    d    0
4  5    e    1
5  1    a    1
```

Comment: This is fine. But I would expect df %>% arrange(1 == 5) or something like that :-)

Comment: @TarJae Haha, I see. Then just I need to think about it :)

Comment: @TarJae I added another option, so you can check if it fits you.

Answer (score 2):

After the whole day of trial and error and your wonderful answers:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
    slice(-1) %>% bind_rows(df %>% slice(1))
```

Output:

```
  ID var1 var2
1  2    b    1
2  3    c    0
3  4    d    0
4  5    e    1
5  1    a    1
```